# How to change default timestamp format in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am brand new to PostgreSQL coming from a few years in a company who solely using MySQL and I am a little caught off guard by the TIMESTAMP type:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    example_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    time_utc TIMESTAMP
);
INSERT INTO example (time_utc) VALUES (NOW());

SELECT * FROM example;

 example_id |          time_utc          
------------+----------------------------
          1 | 2017-11-02 21:37:26.592814
```

I am aware that I can simply cast the field to its less precise form:

```
SELECT example_id, time_utc::timestamp(0)
```

and am also aware that I can declare the precision in the table definition:

```
time_utc TIMESTAMP(0)
```

But is there a way to change this to be the default precision for all `TIMESTAMP` fields? And similarly, is there a way to change the behavior of `NOW()` to match this format (including its lack of timezone)?

For example in MySQL:

```
SELECT NOW();
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2017-11-02 21:41:26 |
+---------------------+
```

PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT NOW();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2017-11-02 21:42:48.855801+00
```

Honestly I just can't think of any time in the past I have wished for more precision out of MySQL's timestamps and the less precise form is objectively easier on the eyes. Is this an easy configuration change or is this just something I need to suck up and deal with in my transition to PostgreSQL?

Thanks

Comment: The display is completely controlled by the SQL client, not by the server. I think the `psql` client honors the [lc_time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#guc-lc-time) configuration

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so when specifying in the table def with `timestamp(0)` (a server side thing), does that just truncate the precision (i.e. the timestamp is stored as `HH:ii:ss.000000`) when inserting?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in other words, all timestamp operations *always* act on the full time (including millis)?

Comment: @thedarklord47: yes, but you can always truncate to the level you want/need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The date/time style can be selected by the user using the `SET datestyle` 
>   command, the DateStyle parameter in the `postgresql.conf`
>   configuration file, or the `PGDATESTYLE environment variable` on the
>   server or client.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#datatype-datetime-output

The available options (masks) are also listed at the same reference. But they may not provide for what you want exactly. Beyond that you have the to_char() function

> The formatting function to_char (see Section 9.8) is also available as
>   a more flexible way to format date/time output.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: Disappointing that we can't have the same options we have with to_char at a global level.